# gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding / gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity?hl=ko

- GSA : gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com
- KSA : default/log-forwarder
- Role : roles/logging.logWriter

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding test-ingest \
--member=serviceAccount:gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role='roles/logging.logWriter'
```

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
--member "serviceAccount:test-ingest.svc.id.goog[default/log-forwarder]"
```

I have confirmed through official documentation that the use of workloadIdentityUser can be achieved using a particular method. However, I also discovered that the projects add-iam-policy-binding command can also be used to add workloadIdentityUser permissions.

I am unsure of the difference between the projects add-iam-policy-binding and iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding commands. It seems that these commands cannot be used to bind GSA and KSA together. I am curious as to why they are being used.

```bash
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding test-ingest \
--member=serviceAccount:gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role='roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser'
```

---

Can binding be done using the following command instead of the top two commands?

It is an iam command, not a project command.

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/logging.logWirter \
--member "serviceAccount:test-ingest.svc.id.goog[default/log-forwarder]"
```

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
--member "serviceAccount:test-ingest.svc.id.goog[default/log-forwarder]"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the level or the resource where you are assigning the IAM Role

Projet level:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding
```

Service Account Level

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding
```

Lastly, with the role **workloadIdentityUser** you are enabling the kubernetes service account to impersonate a Google Service Account, for that moment you only need to assign the IAM roles to the GSA, because the KSA will use that account to interact with the Google Cloud APIs and there is no way to assign directly to a KSA, this command is wrong

```
  gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gke-service@test-ingest.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/logging.logWriter \
--member "serviceAccount:test-ingest.svc.id.goog[default/log-forwarder]"
```

Because you cannot assign the Log Writer Rol at the SA level, and the KSA is not a valid member.

[image]